# Allow users to check start and end points in an embedded youtube video

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, video-player

Is it possible to display an embedded video from youtube on a website and allow users to check a start point and an end point on timeline, and get only the selected video data for further processing?

Do I need to build a second player that will get only the data from Youtube and display it (and then create a system for start/ end points using javascript). Or Does Youtube offer in its API such techniques?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that are unaware, you can already specify a starting point for Youtube videos in the embed code if you want to have a video start at a specific starting point within the video.  In order to do that, you will need to utilize the [start](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#start) parameter whereby you will specify the starting point in seconds.  The video below was embedded using the following code:

```
<object width="425" height="344">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ye9hUGRZZA0&fs=1&start=59"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ye9hUGRZZA0&fs=1&start=59" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed>
</object>
```

here is the clear example for the thing that you want .Please go to this link.And I think that will help you.I got this link from here . [link](http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-deep-linking/) .

[YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#start)